# what if we assign different structures with = operator instead of memcpy()

Tags: c, linux, struct, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

What are the contents of data1 if following code executes?

```
struct {
int a;
char b;
}st1;

struct {
char c;
int d;
}st2;

main()
{
    struct st1 data1 = {0};
    struct st2 data2 = {'A',10};
    data1 = data2;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not valid Ansi code, you must say struct st1 {...}, struct st2 {...},

Comment: If you fix your struct declarations, it still would not compile, you'd get an error, e.g. "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct st1’ from type ‘struct st2’"

Answer (score 1):

This only works if both structs have the same type. Otherwise you must get a compilation error.

(If your compiler generates an executable anyway, it could do anything).

Answer (score 1):

> What are the contents of data1 if following code executes?

Your code can't execute, since it will not compile.
You'd get a compiler error, e.g.

```
"error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct st1’ from type ‘struct st2’"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will lead to an error as st1 and st2 are the objects of the temporary structure. So you better try this out...
You will have to create the objects only during the time define your temporary structure.

```
# include <stdio.h>
struct {
    int a;
    char b;
}st1 = {0};

struct {
    char c;
    int d;
}st2 = {'A', 10};;

int main()
{
//  struct st1 data1 = {0};
//  struct st2 data2 = {'A',10};
//  data1 = data2;
    return 0;
}
```